# How do I Change the Font Text Style in Sony Experia M without rooting phone?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, fonts, sony-xperia

I want to change the default font style on **Sony xperia M** without rooting my phone. How do I do this?

Comment: A good start would be the [most frequented questions tagged "font"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts). Have you checked them? Though, without root, I'm afraid you wont have much luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link that covers some methods for changing the system font on some android phones without root, I don't know if it works on your phone as well: http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-change-the-fonts-on-your-android-phone-32078/

Answer (score 0):

You will find many answer for your question.But here is the simplest way which is I have used.

1. Root your Xperia M (Use towelroot,Root checker,SuperSu)
2. Install iFont.(Other apps may not able to change font.Your phone will just rebooted)
3. It will reboot your phone.
4. And Here it is your font will be seen changed.